# Cypress e2e test dock closing on cy.visit()

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cypress

I'm using Cypress for e2e tests in an angular web app. When cypress first opens it goes to `http://localhost:54401/__/#tests/integration/login.spec.ts`

This shows the cypress test dock on the left side of the screen and the web output to the right. As soon as my `beforeEach` function calls `cy.visit()`, instead of changing the output, the main url at the top of the screen changes to:
`http://localhost:4200/__/#tests/integration/login.spec.ts`

Angular then takes over, it can't find the `__` route, so instead the page is redirected to my default page, and I lose the Cypress dock/test runner.

Cypress should just be changing the frame where my application is loaded, not the page url.  Something is happening that is causing Cypress to manipulate the main browser url instead of the frame url.

[image]

How can this be fixed so that cypress targets the frame and not the main browser window? This has worked in the past and just recently started not working. I'm not sure if it's a cypress or chrome issue. I thought this may be an issue with cypress web security so I did try setting `chromeWebSecurity: false` in `cypress.json` to no avail.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Disabling-Web-Security

I'm using cypress 3.1.5.

Comment: I have the same problem (but with a Vue app running on port 8080). The tests run if I switch to Electron, so I've been doing that while waiting for time to re-install everything. Best guess at the moment it is due to an auto-upgrade from chrome. I am on cypress v3.1.1, Chrome 72, Electron 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filed a bug with the Cypress github project and was informed this usually occurs when an application has framebusting code. Turns out we were importing `hammerjs`. When I removed that import (in polyfills.js), it works fine.

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

For reference, the issue link is [Entire test runner redirects to app's login page #3517](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3517)

Comment: Since `hammerjs` is used for touch screens, I wonder if touch-enabled apps are a class that ***cannot be tested*** with Cypress.

Comment: For what it's worth, I removed `hammerjs` from node_modules, and the reference to it in `angular-cli.json:scripts` (I have no reference in `polyfill.ts`) but the problem persists.

Comment: I just did a clean install of Cypress in a new folder and it is now working, but I note that the chrome test window still switches the base url from `http://localhost:64203/__/#/tests/integration\app.e2e.spec.js` to `http://localhost:4200/__/#/tests/integration\app.e2e.spec.js`, so presume this is expected behaviour. With the fresh install the app remains in it's frame, where-as the previous install it would take over the wole chrome window (then 404 because the route was invalid).

Comment: I think the port change is expected to get around web security problems, as outlined here:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Disabling-Web-Security

Comment: For future reference, does anyone know of code in hammerjs doing the frame busting? I took a quick look and didn't find any. Some other type of interaction may have been at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading from 3.1.0 to 3.1.5 resolved the issue.